# After I stop a mysql import do I have to start again or can I start where I left off?

Tags: mysql

I stopped a mysql import and I was wondering if I have to drop that table and start again or just run the command `load data local infile...`again and it will continue to insert records from where I left off.

Answer (score 0):

It will not continue where it left off, it will begin from the beginning of the file (it will have not idea where it left off), but because you are using the `LOCAL` keyword, from the documentation:

> If you specify IGNORE, input rows that duplicate an existing row on a
>   unique key value are skipped. ... With LOCAL, the default behavior is
>   the same as if IGNORE is specified

So data that has already been loaded will simply be ignored. You can read up on the documentation for `LOAD DATA` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Also why is it when I show table status, the row length always changes

Comment: Because you are in the process of loading data?

Comment: I mean for all tables in my database. Even tables that are not being edited.

Comment: My table is growing past 30 million records which means it is not ignoring any of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IGNORE` keyword as specified [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).